# Shell script creates linux user account but password goes wrong

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication

I've written a shell script to create user accounts. The script reads user account name and password from a text file and create account with those info. When I execute the script it successfully creates the accounts, but when I try to log in to those accounts I can't log in due to `Invalid password, please try again` error.

Here is the script I used to create the user accounts:

```
file_name="t.txt"

while read user pass
do
    useradd -p ${pass} ${user}
done < $file_name
```

**EDIT-1:**
`t.txt` file contains the user account information: space separated username and password per line. Here is the snippet of the file:

```
user1 abcXYZ
user2 DEFxyz
user3 ijkLMN
```

**EDIT-2:**
When I follow the method recommended by Steve Kline it shows me following result: (still the created accounts can't be logged in with the given password)

```
passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'
Usage: passwd [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -a, --all                     report password status on all accounts
  <---------------------------------- SKIPPED ------------------------------->
  -x, --maxdays MAX_DAYS        set maximum number of days before password
                                change to MAX_DAYS

Adding user user1  with the password  abcXYZ123
```

Still the created accounts can't be logged in with the given password

Comment: See if the method posted works.

Comment: Added the result of your recommended method, please see EDIT-2

Comment: What is your environment? Distro, Version, and passwd version. Does this box have Kerberos, BoKs, KeON configured?

Comment: Can you cat a couple from /etc/shadow - how do those look?

Comment: first couple of lines are given in EDIT-3

Comment: I mean a user account that's being created by your script.

Comment: Ok, What about the environment?

Comment: please check the environment

Comment: Sorry Mostafiz, that was way more literal than I meant. I was referring to the host. What distro of Linux, x86/64, is it using Kerberos, boks, or keon, anything of that nature. I'm trying to help figure this out.

Comment: distro is ubuntu 14.04, x64. 
how can I know is it using Kerberos, boks, or keon?

Comment: I updated; should work with echo user:pass | /usr/sbin/chpasswd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your current method is adding plaintext passwords to /etc/shadow.

Using your script as is... Created this. Mind you, I added a few digits at the end of your the password to match the standard 8 characters to suppress the "are you sure" prompts.

```
user1:abcXYZ123:16963:0:99999:7:::
user2:DEFxyz142:16963:0:99999:7:::
user3:ijkLM1564:16963:0:99999:7:::
```

## The users files

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat t.txt s.txt
user1 abcXYZ123
user2 DEFxyz142
user3 ijkLM1564
user4 abcXYZ123
user5 DEFxyz142
user6 ijkLM1564
```

### The Script

```
#!/bin/bash -e
#Adding user1, user2, user3 using your method.
file_name="t.txt"
while read user pass
do
    #useradd ${user} -p ${pass}
    useradd -p ${pass} ${user}
    echo "Adding user "${user}"  with the password  "${pass}
done < $file_name

#Adding user4, user5, user6 using the recommended method.
file_name="s.txt"
while read user pass
do
    #useradd ${user} -p ${pass}
    useradd ${user}
    echo "${pass}" | passwd --stdin ${user}
    echo "Adding user "${user}"  with the password  "${pass}

done < $file_name
```

Using both syntaxes, produced these results in /etc/shadow

```
user1:abcXYZ123:16963:0:99999:7:::
user2:DEFxyz142:16963:0:99999:7:::
user3:ijkLM1564:16963:0:99999:7:::
user4:$1$NpazYQAn$tlhfQLlP0CaFiUeNeK8HW.:16963:0:99999:7:::
user5:$1$4z8G4gvh$v0jzcV5xbhWixU1LG9mwW.:16963:0:99999:7:::
user6:$1$cBkcYJkJ$7A.j6E3gy/umUcVmY0tgt0:16963:0:99999:7:::
```

So, therefor the method I posted works. **Update:** Ubuntu working method below. This the stdin is confirmed for Rhel based systems.

```
useradd ${user}
echo "${pass}" | passwd --stdin ${user}
```

If your heart is absolutely set on using that method, I would suggest installing mkpasswd and using this syntax.

```
 useradd -p $(mkpasswd ${pass}) ${user}
```

Update for Ubuntu Passwd stdin

```
echo ${user}:${pass} | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

Comment: but I need to do it programatically, what's wrong to set password this way?

Comment: Well I'm re-thinking this idea. Can you post the structure of your t.txt document so I can tailor this to your specific needs?

Comment: two space separated string per line: username and password

Comment: Can you post an example by editing your original post.

Comment: Np man, we could have saved a lot of time with that info up front lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114415/discussion-between-steve-kline-and-mostafiz).